# Where can I see my product added by the EBAY API

Tags: ebay-api

I added a couple of products by the **api_test_tool** from the eBay developer page, I can see these product if I use the request from the **SELL** API **getInventoryItems**

Screenshot of my JSON of my products:
[image: Screenshot of my JSON of my products]

I added those products by the request **createOrReplaceInventoryItem**

So my question is, why is there no way to see these products anywhere ?  I mean I have a lot of products add one by one, I was expecting seen these products in the "sell" UI.

One other problem which is certainly in link is that if I use the request **getInventoryItem** with a SKU that I already added with **createOrReplaceInventoryItem**, I never get anything.

I was thinking that maybe I need to give more information's about my products but I didn't find any precise resource about it.

Can someone open my eyes about this process?

(I tried in sandbox and production same result).

Comment: I've also hit upon this as an issue, I can make inventory via the API, but only see it via the API. This is on the live site, Sandbox chucks errors.